# How to display multiple LinkedList elements to look like a table in JAVA?

Tags: java, linked-list, listiterator

I'm new here and it's first time when I post, so please excuse me if I'll make any mistakes. I want to display elements from 4 LinkedList and those elements to be displayed like in a table. I don't need JTable because i don't need GUI. I've tried with ListIterator but it doesn't show them all: I mean if a list has 5 elements and another have 3 will be shown only 3 elements from each list. 
A piece of code worth more than a milion words, so :

```
    LinkedList list1 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList list2 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList list3 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList list4 = new LinkedList();

    list1.addFirst("A");
    list1.addFirst("B");
    list1.addFirst("C");
    list1.addFirst("D");
    list1.addFirst("E");
    list1.addFirst("F");

    list2.addFirst("G");
    list2.addFirst("H");
    list2.addFirst("I");
    list2.addFirst("J");
    list2.addFirst("K");
    list2.addFirst("L");
    list2.addFirst("M");

    list3.addFirst("N");
    list3.addFirst("O");
    list3.addFirst("P");
    list3.addFirst("Q");
    list3.addFirst("R");
    list3.addFirst("S");
    list3.addFirst("T");
    list3.addFirst("U");

    list4.addFirst("V");
    list4.addFirst("W");
    list4.addFirst("X");
    list4.addFirst("Y");
    list4.addFirst("Z");

    ListIterator it1 = list1.listIterator();
    ListIterator it2 = list2.listIterator();
    ListIterator it3 = list3.listIterator();
    ListIterator it4 = list4.listIterator();

    while (it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext() && it3.hasNext() && it4.hasNext()){

        System.out.println(it1.next()+"\t\t\t"+ it2.next()+"\t\t\t"+it3.next()+"\t\t\t"+it4.next());
    }
```

And the output is like this :

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/9/capturelkt.png/]

I am confused why is this the output, so if someone can explain me what I'm doing wrong or can give me a hint or a example, I'll be gratefull. This is not a homework, I'm just kinda learning JAVA alone. Thank you in advance !

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but: Why do you use an `ListIterator` instead of an `Iterator`?

Comment: I expect the first list to be  F E D C B A , second M L K J I H G; just as i declared them.

Comment: Realize that the lists will output in reverse order as created because addFirst() always adds to the front of the list, so the last element added will be the first to be returned by next().

Comment: yes, because i wanted to make it behave as a Stack. The Stack from Java is inherited from Vector, so it's not a real Stack...

Comment: @Survivor why would inheriting from Vector not be a real stack? Stack is about behavior, not implementation. The `java.util.Stack` is a real stack, even if it is implemented using a usually-unnecessary synchronization mechanism.

Comment: @Survivor how is it not a "real stack"?

Comment: Well, for example, if you add 1,2,3,4,5 in a Java Stack Container you will have them 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 instead of 5, 4, 3, 2, 1. That's what I meant; I'm getting confused sometimes, so that's why i made a LinkedList to work like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you don't see the row with `A` in it is because of this line:

```
it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext() && it3.hasNext() && it4.hasNext()
```

As soon as one of your lists is out of elements, you stop.

To fix it you have to continue to work until ALL your lists are out of elements. But, you can't just access those lists if they're out of elements, so you have to work around it.

```
// change && to ||
while(it1.hasNext() || it2.hasNext() || it3.hasNext() || it4.hasNext()) {
    Object[] objs = new String[] { "", "", "", ""}; // empty strings
    // if iterators on this row are not empty, replace with values
    if(it1.hasNext()) objs[0] = it1.next();
    if(it2.hasNext()) objs[1] = it2.next();
    if(it3.hasNext()) objs[2] = it3.next();
    if(it4.hasNext()) objs[3] = it4.next();
    // now print
    String tabs = "\t\t\t";
    System.out.println(objs[0] + tabs + objs[1] + tabs + objs[2] + tabs + objs[3]);

}
```

This would be faster without the array, and instead used a strict number of objects. But I see it as cleaner and easier to refactor if we leave it as an array.

Comment: Thank you a lot corsiKa. A very simple and clever way to solve it. You are the best !

Answer (score 1):

it prints from the start so as you are printing next(iterating through it) you will print the most recently added item, because you are adding items to teh start each time)

with this line

```
while (it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext() && it3.hasNext() && it4.hasNext()){
```

you are also only printing only if all lists have a next value, only 5 values are printed because your shortest list is only has a size of 5(list 4)

Comment: Thank you Sean, you are right; I understand now. Then is a way to print those lists like this : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/96/capturedwz.png/ (I'm not an artist in paint, my excuse).

Answer (score 1):

You're using `&&` so the moment an iterator's `hasNext()` returns false, the entire evaluation of `(it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext() && it3.hasNext() && it4.hasNext())` will be false.